# Download pdf file on client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf

I am a beginner for MEAN stack. I want to download and display a pdf file to the client.  For that my server side script as under:

```
app.get("/pdf", function(req, res)
    {
        var file = __dirname + '/try.pdf';
        res.download(file, function (err) 
            {
               if (err) {
                   console.log("Error " + err);
               } else {
                   console.log("Success");  // server shows success but file is not downloaded to client 
               }
               res.end();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

After starting server when I give command localhost/pdf in browser the file is downloaded. 
But, when I connect to server through index page and attach this module to ng-click event of a button, server shows 
success but the file is not downloaded to client. My angularJS code is as under which also displays both success and
then clause message:

```
        app.controller('showPDF', function($scope, $http)
            {
                $scope.pdfShow = function()
                {
                    alert("Inside pdfShow");

                    $http.get("/pdf" ).
                    success(function(response){alert("PDF Success")}).
                    error(function(error, status){alert("PDF Error " + error + " status " + status); }).
                    then(function(response){alert("PDF then clause ")})
                } 
            }
        );


        <button ng-controller="showPDF" ng-click="pdfShow()">Show PDF file </button>
```

Is there any mistake I am doing?  Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: One issue I see is that the res.end() being inside the res.download callback, try moving it outside the res.download. Also, I'd recommend you look into streams and fs.statFile sync to see if the file exists.

Comment: Why do you need to fetch it with an XHR? Just put this [basic HTML](https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) without any angular or js involved at all: `<a href="/pdf" download="document.pdf">Show PDF file</a>`

Comment: @idbehold won't that expose the path to the stored file on the server. xhr request masks the location of assets on the server.

Comment: @Vish xhrs won't really mask the location though because anyone could just open up the network inspector and see the path anyways.

Comment: @idbehold that request will only show path to the /get route req and won't disclose location to the file where it's stored on the server.

Comment: @Vish okay, well the path to the /get route is the only thing exposed by my solution, too. So I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: This <a href="/pdf" download="document.pdf">Show PDF file</a> worked. But, I can't understand why it is not working with button.  Anyhow, thanks a lot idbehold!